# Printing both outcomes of if statements

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in python and was trying to write a simple programme for deciding if you were eligible for a loan or not but regardless of my inputs both of the outputs are printed, I think it is an issue with my if statements?

```
response1=input('Do you have a high income?  ').lower()
if response1== 'yes':
    high_income=True
elif response1== 'no':
    high_income=False
response2=input('Do you have good credit?  ').lower()
if response2=='yes':
    good_credit=True
elif response2=='no':
    good_credit=False

if high_income or good_credit:False
print ('Sorry, you are not eligable for a loan!')

if high_income and good_credit:True
print('Congratulations you are eligable for a loan!')
```

Comment: Your `print()` statements aren't inside the `if` blocks.

Comment: You need to review the syntax of `if`. `:False` and `:True` don't do what you think they do.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, when you say inside the if blocks is that like the ones above where it says good_credit? if that's the case I get an indentation error saying unexpected indent?

Comment: Python allows one-line `if` statements where the code to run is after `:` on the same line, instead of indented on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

When you put code immediately after `:`, it's treated as the body of the `if` statement. So your code is equivalent to:

```
if high_income or good_credit:
    False

print ('Sorry, you are not eligable for a loan!')

if high_income and good_credit:
    True

print('Congratulations you are eligable for a loan!')
```

As you can see, the `print()` statements are not controlled by the `if` conditions, so they're both printed unconditionally. The `True` and `False` lines don't actually do anything, but any expression is a valid statement.

What you want is:

```
if high_income and good_credit:
    print('Congratulations you are eligable for a loan!')
else:
    print('Sorry, you are not eligable for a loan!')
```

Note that I've also used `else:` rather than writing another `if` whose condition is the opposite of the first. This is less error-prone, since it can be confusing to invert complex conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```py
if not (high_income and good_credit):
    print('not eligible')
else:
    print('eligible')
```

Whenever code is in a block, it needs to be indented **four** spaces from the surrounding code. In addition, since your `high_income` and `good_credit` variables are booleans, you can simply use them without comparing them to `True` or `False`. And since there are only two options, whether they get the loan or not, you can use an `if-else` statement and remove the second condition.

Comment: it should be `if not (high_income and good_credit):`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax you wanted:

```
if not high_income or not good_credit:
    print ('Sorry, you are not eligable for a loan!')

if high_income and good_credit:
    print('Congratulations you are eligable for a loan!')
```

Of course, in this case the second `if` could be replaced by an `else:`, but this shows you the syntax.

Here's another hint.  This:

```
if response1== 'yes':
    high_income=True
elif response1== 'no':
    high_income=False
```

can be replaced by:

```
high_income = response1 == 'yes'
```

As it is, your code will explode if the user answers anything other than "yes" or "no" (modulo case), because `high_income` will not be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Python is an Object Oriented Language and we need to treat it as such whenever it's possible. Therefore, I believe it's important to provide a complete answer than focusing only on a simple indentation mistake.

First, we need to decompose the problem into smaller problems, that can be easier to solve.

In practice, your program asks a series of questions and given the answers, it provides a final answer.

So, let's create a Question object.

```py
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question: str, score: int = 0):
        self.question = question.lower()
        self.score = score
    
    def ask(self):
        response = input(self.question)
        return response == 'yes'
    
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score if self.ask() else -self.score
```

This object not only asks the user a question, but also it gives a score according to the answer, which is very useful in our case.

Then we need to create an object that evaluates a series of the object Question and give a final result.

```py
class Questionnaire:
    def __init__(self, threshold: int):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.questions = []
    
    def add_question(self, question: LoanQuestion):
        self.questions.append(question)
    
    def run_questionnaire(self):
        total_score = sum([q.get_score() for q in self.questions])
        if total_score >= self.threshold:
            print('Congratulations you are eligable for a loan!')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you are not eligable for a loan!')
```

What's the result?

```py
question_1 = Question('Do you have a high income?', score=5)
question_2 = Question('Do you have good credit?', score=5)
question_3 = Question('Do you like pineapple pizza?', score=0)

questionnaire = Questionnaire(threshold=10)

questionnaire.add_question(question_1)
questionnaire.add_question(question_2)
questionnaire.add_question(question_3)

questionnaire.run_questionnaire()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement :** The person is eligible to get loan from bank? 
**Condition :** He/She should have high income and good credit, to get loan.

```
res1 = input("Do you have high income (yes/no): ")
res2 = input("Do you have good credit (yes/no): ")
if (res1 and res2) == 'yes':
   print("You are eligible to get loan")
else:
   print("You are not eligible to get loan")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this. Print Congratulations only when both high income and high credit are true, otherwise print Sorry, not eligible.

```
response1=input('Do you have a high income?  ').lower()
if response1== 'yes':
    high_income=True
elif response1== 'no':
    high_income=False
response2=input('Do you have good credit?  ').lower()
if response2=='yes':
    good_credit=True
elif response2=='no':
    good_credit=False

if high_income and good_credit:
    print('Congratulations you are eligable for a loan!')
else:
    print ('Sorry, you are not eligable for a loan!')
```